# Working of corrective lenses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, lenses

I was reading about vision defects like myopia and hypermetropia .

In one question it was asked whether the corrective lenses change the size of the object or not.

I think it should change the size of the object but in the answer it was written that it just moves the object to the far point or to the near point of the eye while the angular size remains the same.

please explain what is angular size and what happens to the size of the object.